# How do I pull inner elements from a Selenium web element in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium to pull the stock symbols from this page and insert them into a list:
https://www.barchart.com/stocks/highs-lows/highs?timeFrame=1y

My code:

```
StockList = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/highs-lows/highs?timeFrame=1y"
driver.get(url)

stock_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for stock in stock_list:
    stock.find_element_by_name("data-current-symbol=")
    print(stock)
```

I receive a `NoSuchElementException`.

When I inspect the page, each `tr` has the following: `"data-current-symbol="ACY`

How can I pull out the stock symbol?

Comment: I guess, the `=` should not be there  in `instock.find_element_by_name("data-current-symbol=")`

Comment: Removed `=` and changed to `stock.find_element_by_name("data-current-symbol")` - it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
tr[data-current-symbol]
```

And utilize `.get_attribute` method:

```
StockList = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/highs-lows/highs?timeFrame=1y"
driver.get(url)

stock_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[data-current-symbol]")

for stock in stock_list:
    symbol = stock.get_attribute('data-current-symbol')
    print(symbol)
    StockList.append(symbol)
```